# Function that splits word

Tags: recursion, scheme

I wanted to write a function that splits a word into first, middle, and last characters and creating an individual list for each character. For example:

The word "codes" would be split into:

```
(list #\c "ode" #\s)
```

then

```
(list #\c #\o "d" #\e #\s)
```

then

```
(list #\c #\o #\d #\e #\s)
```

So basically it takes any word and then splits off the first and last character, then repeat the process until every character is converted. Could someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Which scheme are you using?

Comment: @Shawn I'm using Racket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd love to help you with this. Here is my help:

- You can differentiate between characters and strings using `string?` and `char?`
- A string is a vector of characters. You can get the length with `string-length` and access individual characters with `string-ref`.
- Strings and vectors are zero indexed like all good languages. Use `+` and `-` to calculate the needed index.
- Use `substring` to create the new middle string.
- You use `car`, `cdr`, and `cons` for the actual list parts.
- Scheme only real looping construct is recursion. named `let` is often used in cases like this.
- The logic should be to cons the first element nd recurse until you find a string. There you calculate the index of the last element. You then `cons` the first, `cons` the new middle, cons the new last letter, the rest of the list goes as the last cdr. You now have one round.
- You need a outer loop if you want this to happen until the list no longer has a string it it. The inner loop needs to know what to do if you end up with the empty list.

Here is a procedure that iterates until it hits a string, then replaces it with another. Your inner loop would look much like it:

```
(define (replace-first-string lst replacement)
  (let helper ((lst lst))
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((string? (car lst)) (cons replacement (cdr lst)))
          (else (cons (car lst) (helper (cdr lst)))))))

(replace-first-string (list #\c "ode" #\s) "here")
; ==> (#\c "here" #\s)
```

This is not a very efficent procedure to make a list of characters. In Scheme we already have `string->list` which produces the same end result.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I also want to know how to convert the string in the order that I mentioned in the question: first and last characters, then make the middle into another word, then break this word into first and last characters, and repeat.

Comment: @Badajoz I've added an example iterator. This should be enough for you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help